# Getting batch id after scheduling a batch

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am using the method `System.scheduleBatch` , this method returns the scheduled job ID (CronTrigger ID). However, I need also the batch id because I need to monitor the bach. Is there any way I can also get the batch id of course without looking at the "Apex Jobs" queue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, you could try using this query `CronTrigger job = 
    [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Id, CronJobDetail.Name, CronJobDetail.JobType 
    FROM CronTrigger ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];` I believe the parameter CronJobDetail.Id would give you the batch Id

Comment: I queried all the fields on CronTrigger to check whether the batch job id is eventually updated, but no luck.

Comment: that is true but I need the batch id right after calling 'System.scheduleBatch'. So that I can monitor the batch.

Comment: If you need to monitor the batch immediately, why not use `executeBatch()` to enqueue it synchronously?

Comment: If you know the apexclass id you might be able to use `AsyncApexJob` object. `SELECT Id, ApexClassID FROM AsyncapexJob where ApexClassID = 'xxxxxxxxx'`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the batch id directly by using the method `System.scheduleBatch`; however, a combination of the apex scheduler and the method `Database.executeBatch` can do the trick. In other words, use the regular `Database.executeBatch` which will return the job id, and schedule the batch job using the apex scheduler.